# VS19 Create Visual Jpeg of Code

Tags: printing, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, code

I want to create a jpeg image of my code with black bg and white/color font as seen in dark mode. This is to get it printed and framed for my wall but I'm having such a hard time figuring it out. I went into my options and changed print and cut/copy functions but didn't have luck. Any help would be nice! TIA

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What if you just take a screenshot of it, paste it into Paint, and save as jpg? Or use the Snip & Sketch tool built in to Windows (`Windows key` + `Shift` + `S`) and save it

Comment: What part of this process are you having difficulties with? How are you trying to do this?